# Modal Delete cannot delete first item

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

Having some issues with my flask app. I am trying to use modal to delete a row from my database. Essentially I ran a for loop for each 'image' in my database, and I have tagged a unique ID to each modal. With the modal, I am able to delete any image I want, except for the very first image, with ID of 1.

HTML CODE:

```
            {% if images %}
            {% for image in images.items %}
                <div class="content-section">
                    <div class="media align-items-center">
                        <img class="w-75 rounded" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='questionbank/' + image.img) }}">
                        <div class="text-center media-body">
                            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{{ url_for('homeworks.update_questionbank',questionbank_id=image.id) }}">Update Questionbank <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></a>

                            <button type = "button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteQB{{image.id}}">Delete Questionbank <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></button>
                            <h3><span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">Qn: {{ image.id }}</span></h3>
                            <h3><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Answer: {{ image.answer }}</span></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Modal-->
                <div class="modal fade" id="deleteQB{{image.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Delete Questionbank?</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <form action="{{ url_for('homeworks.delete_questionbank', questionbank_id=image.id) }}" method="POST">
                                    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

Routes.py code.

```
@homeworks.route("/questionbank/<int:questionbank_id>/delete", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required    

def delete_questionbank(questionbank_id):
    qb = Questionbank.query.get_or_404(questionbank_id)
    delete_q = Questionbank.__table__.delete().where(Questionbank.id == questionbank_id)
    db.session.execute(delete_q)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Your questionbank has been deleted!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('homeworks.questionbank', grade="ALL",tags="ALL",difficulty="ALL"))
```

Comment: What happens when you try to delete that? Do you receive an error?

Comment: it just reloads the page again for me. If i set a simple print statement in the route, nothing gets printed so I am guessing the url_for route wasn't even triggered by the modal

Comment: Does it exist in the storage?

Comment: Yup, its the first row in my database. Im targetting it with data-target="#deleteQB{{image.id}}", where image.id will equal to 1.